# how to hide error message window produced by process started

Tags: c#, process, command-line-interface

I am using C# to interact with a program's command line interface. Everything is fine except an Error Message Window pops up when the program encounters an error. This program does not exit until the user clicks the "OK" button on the Error Window. How can I bypass this GUI window? 
Note, I don't want to start this process in another desktop as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143206/creating-hidden-processes-window-not-visible), because the program will not exit until the "OK" button is clicked. I want the program to exit regardless of success or failure.

Note `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` doesn't work. My code is below.

```
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "path to program";
    startInfo.Arguments = "command line arguments";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.WaitForExit();
    int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
    Console.WriteLine("exit code " + exitCode);
```

Comment: You can't *bypass* the window.  Even if you *could* hide it, the user would still have to press OK; but of course can't because it would be hidden.

Comment: is there anyway to close the window or click the "OK" button in C#? The exit code already provides enough information.

Comment: See other questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223872/programatically-press-a-button-on-another-application-c-windows

Comment: thanks for the pointer! luckily I've found a "silent" option in the CLI, so can avoid this for now...